# How to display textbox when user click on link?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to display 2 textbox when user click on the link

```
//when user click on this link then display below two textbox
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="#" Text="More Questions?" runat="server" /> 

<%--first textbox--%>    
First:<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="t1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<%--second textbox--%>
Second:<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="t2" runat="server"> 
</asp:TextBox>
```

I want to display 2 textbox when user click on the link now displaying the textbox and link together.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

in this case using Javascript or JQuery would be the easiest solution.

you could do something like this:

```
  $('[id*=hyperlink1]').on('click',function(){
     $('[id*=t1]').show();
     $('[id*=t2]').show();
  });
```

Another possible solution would be to change the `asp:hyperlink` for a `asp:linkbutton` and change the visibility on the `OnClick` event.

Comment: thanks your answer work perfectly but one issue is when I click on link first time then not display the textbox and click on second time on link then display the textbox ```<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="#" Text="More Questions?" onclick="show();" runat="server" />``` help